# JavaScript: Sending comma separated string of parameters to a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am having a function in javascript as

```
function add(v1,v2){

var add=v1+v2;

}
```

Now I am calling this function as below -

```
write.out(var param="1,2";);

write.out(window[add](param););
```

Using the above call, it's not working. What it does is it gives the complete string "1,2" as value to the first param(v1) of the function.

Its working if I call the function in following way -

```
write.out(var param1="1";);

write.out(var param2="2";);

write.out(window[add](param1,param2););
```

I want to achieve it using the first way where i can send the parameters as a comma separated string of parameters.

Can some one help me out how this can be done...

Thanks!!!

Comment: Don't you mean window.add or window['add']?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make usage of ECMAscripts `.apply()`, which calls a function and accepts an array of paramters.

```
window['add'].apply(null, param.split(','));
```

That way, we execute the `add` function, setting its context to `null` (you could also change that if you need) and pass in the two paramters. Since we need an `Array`, we call `split()` on the string before.

So basically, the above line is the same as

```
add(1,2);
```

Since you're haveing that function in the global context (`window`), we don't even need to write it that explicitly.

```
add.apply(null, param.split(','));
```

will just be fine.